# In Common Lisp why does the macro OR use a gensym, but not AND?

Tags: macros, lisp, common-lisp, sbcl

In Common Lisp (SBCL 1.0.58) why does the macro OR use a gensym, but not AND?

For example,

```
    CL-USER> (macroexpand '(and 1 2 3 4 5))
    (IF 1
        (AND 2 3 4 5)
        NIL)
    T
    CL-USER> (macroexpand '(or 1 2 3 4 5))
    (LET ((#:G967 1))
      (IF #:G967
          #:G967
          (OR 2 3 4 5)))
    T
    CL-USER>
```

I looked at defboot.lisp where the macros are defined but found nothing relevant in the comments.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That's because the implemented logic operators are intended to be [short-circuiting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) and to return the value produced by the last form they evaluated.

To achieve this, `and` does not need a `gensym` because the last form it evaluates will either produce `NIL` or be the result of the final tail call to itself.

On the other hand, `or` has to return the first non-`NIL` value it evaluates, so it cannot rely on the tail call. It needs a `gensym` to do that, because without one:

```
(IF 1
    1
    (OR 2 3 4 5))
```

`1` appears twice in the expansion, and in our case that means the expression that produces `1` is evaluated *twice*. [And you never want that in your macros](https://web.archive.org/web/20160922010203/http://www.bookshelf.jp/texi/onlisp/onlisp_11.html#SEC78).

Comment: Yes, I see that now. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Let's say `a` is false, but `b`, `c`, and `d` are true.  Now, because of short-circuiting we have:

```
(or  a b c d) => b
(and a b c d) => nil
(or    b c d) => b
(and   b c d) => d
```

As you can see, in the `AND` case, the value of the leftmost argument is never used as the return value of the form (unless there is only one argument, in which case the expansion is different).  In the `OR` case, on the other hand, the value of the leftmost argument is the return value if it is true.  Therefore, `AND` can discard the value after testing it for truthiness (and thus does not need to store it in a temporary variable), but `OR` can't.